# How to read rosparam in a launch file

Tags: roslaunch, rosbag, rosparam, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am aiming to write a  bag recording launch script for two same robots with different storage configuration, hence the stored location for the robots will be different.
The robots name are in rosparam.  How do I read the publishing /robot_name in a launch script and then do a if statement to change  my current recording node .

```
 <group if="$(eval arg('robot_name') == robot_name_rosparam)">
      <node pkg="rosbag" type="record" args="record -o /directory /topics">
 <group>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339208/how-to-read-rosparam-in-a-launch-file/) by [chaoshydra](https://answers.ros.org/users/44228/chaoshydra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-12-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2019-12-05**:
[#q213145](https://answers.ros.org/question/213145/use-rosparam-get-in-launch-file/) is dealing with something similar, take a look and see if that's what you are trying to do.

**Comment by [chaoshydra](https://answers.ros.org/users/44228/chaoshydra/) on 2019-12-05**:
@Choco93, I did check that answer when I was searching. It is for loading yaml file to set rosparameter. In my case, the rosparam is already set, I wish to read its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is one way that can be done.

```
<arg name="foo"/>
<arg name="bar"/>
<arg name ="dir1" value="directory1"/>

<node pkg="rosbag" type="record" name="recorder" args="-o $(arg dir1)/($arg foo)"/>
```

and you launch this file like `roslaunch my_pkg my_launch.launch foo:=$(rosparam get foo)`.

---

Originally posted by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) with karma: 685 on 2019-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-06**:
Pedantic, but this is using `arg`s, which are not the same as ROS parameters.

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2019-12-06**:
Yeah, have to get that param into launchfile somehow. Might be possible to do it directly in launchfile but couldn't find a way for that.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-06**:
I don't believe it's actually supported.

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2019-12-06**:
What my answer suggests works, don't know about doing same within launchfile.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-06**:
Yes, it works, but it doesn't actually use ROS parameters.

But perhaps this is already what the OP was asking for. Let's wait and see.

**Comment by [chaoshydra](https://answers.ros.org/users/44228/chaoshydra/) on 2019-12-09**:
Yes, I have done something like that by passing a variable in the launch file.